# Connect to Wi-Fi without internet Android 7

Tags: android, android-wifi

When I'm trying to connect to Wi-Fi without Internet accsess my android 7 shows notification message with question about confirmation for connecting to this Wi-Fi. Before appearance of this notification and users action my app can't open socket. The main problem is that notification appears not immediately after connection.

Question: Is it possible to show this system notification when user opens app?